# how to use vasprintf() with special characters (%)?

Tags: c, linux, string, printf, format-specifiers

I have the following  sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int test(const char *fmt,...)
{
        va_list args;
        char *vacmd=NULL;

        va_start(args,fmt);
        vasprintf(&vacmd, fmt, args);
        printf("vacmd is %s\n", vacmd);

        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
        int ret = 0;
        char *cmd="@wilso%nqw";
        ret = test(cmd);
}
```

Output is :

> vacmd is @wilsoqw

It removed the `%n` from the string.
So my question is does `vasprintf()` works with specials characters or not? or am I missing something?

Comment: you need `"%%"`, since `"%n"` itself is a conversion specifier.

Comment: You don't want to use `vasprintf`, or you did not read its documentation on [vasprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vasprintf.3.html)

Comment: I wish we had a close reason on RTFM and/or common sense. Seriously, just think about it. If all conversion specifiers start with `%`, then how **possibly** could poor `printf()` magically read your mind and deduce that you didn't *intend* to use one particular `%` character as a formatting command?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Also, If I'm not wrong, the present code exhibits UB, due to missing argument to `%n`, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh exactly.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  Note: poor `printf()` still is unable to print `'\0'` from a format string - - certainly not much of a loss though.  C _could_ have specified `"%\0"` to print `'\0'`, but _that_ would run into trouble with the definition of a format _string_.  IAC, poor `printf()` has many issues and its overworked and under appreciated.  Would not surprise me if it went on strike.

Comment: "You don't want to use vasprintf" Why not? What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2):

For `printf()` and family functions,

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character `%`.

So, the `%` in a format string has a special meaning when used with `printf()`/`scanf()` family. You can use `%%` to *discard* the special meaning.

To quote the standard in this regard, from `fprintf()` function specification

> `%`
>
> A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete
>   conversion specification shall be `%%`.

---

<sup>FWIW, your current code exhibits [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as *"If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined."* As per your code, there is no argument supplied for `%n` *format specifier*.</sup>